# Draw new clusters Google Maps Api

Tags: android, google-maps

I have some issues with calling the Cluster Manager's cluster() method, for drawing clusters when OnCameraChanged event is triggered.

I am using the same method for reloading clusters when I simply create a cluster and go back to Map Fragment, the cluster will be there all the time. But whenever I try to reload clusters onCameraChange event, I can see I have the markers, but nothing is getting drawn.

This is the method I use for reloading clusters :

```
private void reloadClusters(ArrayList<Checkin> checkins) {

        if (checkins != null && checkins.size() > 0) {
            for (Checkin item : checkins) {
                mClusterManager.addItem(item);
            }
            mClusterManager.cluster();
        }
    }
```

Since I need to cluster items and trigger the onCameraChange as well, I do the following:

```
getmMap().setOnCameraChangeListener(mClusterManager);
```

Also, within my Map Fragment, I have an inner class that extends the DefaultClusterRenderer which implements the OnCameraChange listener :

```
private class CheckinRenderer extends DefaultClusterRenderer<Checkin> implements GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener {

public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {

            radius = getRadius();
            int zoom_level = Math.round(getmMap().getCameraPosition().zoom);

            LatLng latLng = getmMap().getCameraPosition().target;
            final double lat = latLng.latitude;
            final double lng = latLng.longitude;

            if (zoom_level > 6.5) {
```

Whenever the zoom level is smaller than 6.5, I query the server for information which helps me create the marker, if the return is not null, I use the reload method mentioned above with the result, hoping I will see the clusters drawn.

Comment: For the `clusters` on google map, you may use the `Google Maps Android API utility library` [here](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils).